# C# / .NET GUI development utils

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know about any API's, IDE's or such that simplifies the development of user interfaces? What I'm after is easy positioning and displaying of text, shapes, simple graphics and so on. It should also allow a rather dynamic aproach (easy to move things around, draw new shapes and objects etc post-initiated EDIT: As comment below says, by post-initiated I mean at runtime).

Thanks,

Jonas

Comment: I believe the key phrase here is "post-initiated" which is unhelpfully hidden right at the end. I presume by this you mean at runtime. It may be worth making this more explicit in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WPF (itself a GUI API) there's [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx), which is a tool (AFAIK written in .NET) that focuses on graphical design for WPF and Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2005/2008

Comment: Quite an obvious one, but not what I was looking for :)
thanks though